# Inferring classification of Clifford algebras from classification of Clifford modules

Tags: representation-theory, clifford-algebras, algebras, semi-simple-rings

Let $Cl_n$ be the Clifford algebra (over reals)
$$
Cl_n = T^{*}\mathbb{R}^n/\langle v\otimes v - q(v) \rangle.
$$
There is a periodic table of $K$-representations of $Cl_n$, i.e. $\mathbb{R}$-linear maps
$$
Cl_n \to \operatorname{Hom}_{K}(W,W)  
$$
e.g. for $K=\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},\mathbb{H}.$ For instance, there is a unique irreducible $\mathbb{C}$-representation of $Cl_{n=2m}$ with $W=\mathbb{C}^{2^m}$ and two inequivalent $\mathbb{C}$-irreps of $Cl_{n=2m+1}$ with the same $W$.

The question is whether I could infer the classification of Clifford algebras themselves from the representations, e.g. by using the Artin-Wedderburn theorem. Is Artin-Wedderburn directly applicable, so that the following is true?

$$
\begin{align}
Cl_{n=2m}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C} &\simeq \operatorname{Mat}_{2^m}(\mathbb{C}) ,
\\
Cl_{n=2m+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C} &\simeq \operatorname{Mat}_{2^m}(\mathbb{C}) \oplus \operatorname{Mat}_{2^m}(\mathbb{C}).
\end{align}
$$

If this is the case, one may expect that the full information of $Cl_n$ should come from its $\mathbb{R}$-irreps. Is it true?

Comment: Information about the complex representations at best tells you the complexification, which is not enough information to determine the Clifford algebra. The real representations would do it (you need to know the endomorphism rings of the simple modules and their dimensions).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I see. The endomorphism rings may consist of matrix rings over $\mathbb{R,C,H}$, etc. And which field appears would follow from the maximal commuting algebra $Cl_{n-1}\simeq Cl^{0}_{n} \leq Cl_n$. Am I right?

Comment: No, the endomorphism ring of a simple module is always a division ring (no matrix ring). I don't know what you mean about the maximal commuting algebra.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you for pointing out my confusion. Is there a systematic way to compute the endomorphism rings of simple modules?

Comment: In general I don't know but for Clifford algebras it should be very classical.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you. I will dig further.